# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

While Compiling the WPF Application for many times in a day it give following error

'Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'

Can anyone know why this error occured and how to remove that error.

But if visual studio is restarted then there is no such problem.

thanks in advance

Comment: Not quite enough information to answer...

Comment: But you can ask for further information if you don't understand the question. I think there is no need to give -ve marking . What more information you need ????

Comment: Is there anymore info in the build log? you seem to have only provided one line...is your Studio Service Packed? Are you using any third party code?

Comment: This the the exception which is given in the Description of the error window.

Comment: From the View menu, pick 'output', or use CTRL+W,O to show the output window. In the output window, select 'Build' in the Show output from dropdown. VS will now display progress of the build process which may give you some clue as to what aspect of the build may be causing the memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that your compiler has a memory leak, or that a plugin of your compiler has a memory leak.

There is not your fault, though. It's most probably your compiler's fault. You are encouraged to reproduce the problem and send it to your compiler vendor for a detail investigation.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me frequently with visual studio 2008. I just assume there's a memory leak somewhere due to poor coding on Microsoft's part. Whenever i see this error I close down and reopen visual studio and it compiles without a hitch.

Comment: My code is not at all bug free. Nobody's is, and I think that's the point.. 

My code is not yet running, visual studio is. The out of memory error was caused by visual studio running out of memory while trying to *compile* my code. This error goes away when visual studio is closed and reopened. This series of events show that a memory leak on Visual Studio's part (or an associated tool) is the most likely scenario.

Comment: Ah, I guess the "poor coding" bit was uncalled for. Creating a compiler as large as Visual Studio can not be easy, so I apologize for that comment. The Microsoft Engineers I have meet are all top notch. Do I still believe the problem lies in visual studio? Yes. Do I believe that is a sign of poor coding? No, it's a sign of not being perfect, which no one is.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are saying that after compiling a WPF application many times in Visual Studio you receive an `OutOfMemoryException` error.  Can you elaborate further on where exactly this error shows up?

- In the Designer
- In the output window
- etc ...

It's possible that there is a bug in either a 3rd party hosted control on the designer or in Visual Studio itself.  If you are not using any 3rd party controls then I encourage you to file a bug on connect for the issue.

- http://connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

Is your machine up to the minimum specification for developing WPF applications

Comment: The OP problem is that the `OutOfMemoryException` was thrown when the machine was compiling the code many times over, so it's more likely a memory leak issue rather than machine spec issue

Comment: Agreed, but VS will run in machines of lower spec than the recommendation. While it appears to work it will cause OOM exceptions eventually. The question is too vague and there is not enough information provided for anyone to answer...